# Angular 2. How can I bootstrap mobile app if a device is not desktop

Tags: angular, initialization

I need something like that

```
let supportsTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
let Module= supportsTouch ? MobileApp : DesktopApp;
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(Module);
```

But i've got:
Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.

Maybe someone faced this problem.

Comment: the error basically says, compiler cannot statically analyze the module, because it cannot determine the module without a browser. Are using AOT?  or angular-cli by chance?Also, I'd advise not t do the module switch this way, you might see other AOT issues.

Comment: I use angular-cli.Could you help me with approach to do that?

Comment: when running `ng serve` this works because it's using JIT, while running serve or build in `prod` profile uses AOT. AOT needs to be able to statically analyze your code, it cant do that with the code you are doing. Unless you want to use JIT (with systemjs) for your production.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use abc - https://github.com/thruthesky/abcframework which will bundle Angular into Cordova apps.

abc gives a great convenience when you are working with Angular and want to build mobile apps.

[image]